# Is there a way to create a model and export it into a spriteset of that model 360 view?g

Tags: modeling, 2d

There is an example of a ship model that has a sprite every 22.5 degrees.

[image: img]

How can I export a model I make like that is that possible?

Comment: A number of links related to creating Spritesheets from models in Blender  https://www.blendernation.com/2018/09/05/lets-make-2d-isometric-sprites-from-a-3d-model/  https://www.blendernation.com/2018/09/04/technique-to-create-pre-rendered-sprites-in-blender-and-how-to-use-them-in-godot/ https://www.blendernation.com/?s=sprite

Answer (score 1):

You can't export a model as a picture, you have to render it. To make this easy you can animate the camera. For this method of course you have to compose your image so you have to adjust the lights and the materials (or the freestyle lines if you want) of your model. I made a test file what renders the sprite what you ask. Below on the picture you can see what has been adjusted. Here you can download it: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cycLaGQa0nDICk0urIDQMv2DqP8xw_aO

Just swap the monkey to your own model and click on Animation.

[image]