# How to make camera rotate around object and take pictures from different angles?

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

Please give me a script example of how to make camera rotate around object and take pictures from different angles

Comment: Have you tried anything and if so what failed?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/142076/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-model-and-export-it-into-a-spriteset-of-that-model-36/142146#142146

Comment: No, I have no idea how to do it @Jackdaw

Comment: Probably easier to setup the camera/scene beforehand and just trigger the animation/rendering by script. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2r0KsLYr3wA

Comment: Or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3476/how-can-i-animate-the-camera-in-a-perfect-circular-rotation-around-a-fixed-posit/3477 for rotating the camera instead of the object. This seems like a suitable approach that could be replicated by a script.

Comment: You might find some useful options [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/130404/35559)

Comment: I created a similar script, capturing the commands to use directly from Blender http://www.jumpstation.co.uk/flog/Jan2018.html#p270120181716

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a script.

1) Set up your scene.

2) Position your camera for the first image.

3) Set a keyframe for the camera location and rotation.

4) Move to the next frame in the timeline.

5) Position the camera for the next image.

6) Set key frames as before.

7) Repeat until you have set up all the pictures you need.

8) In the animation settings, set it to create separate images (eg PNG).

9) Set the start and end frame numbers for the animation.

10) Start rendering the animation.  Blender will then create a still image for each of the frames you have set up.

Comment: Yeh, that's what I want, but I need to script it, so I can reuse it